# Mistake in Karp's paper on NP-Complete problems?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions

I read [on a blog](http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2011/10/if-you-find-mistake-in-someone-elses.html) that there are mistakes in Karp's paper where he proved that 0-1 programming is NP-Complete, but I couldn't find it, can anyone explain? And I doubt that there are also mistakes where he proved Steiner Tree Problem is NP-Compelete but not sure.

The blog post a little old and I thought asking the writer of the blog may not receive answer quickly enough. I didn't find any referrence in other places so I thought this question may worth asking.

Comment: it appears in this case fortnow/gasarch (authors of the blog) may be hinting that that particular proof is not exactly correct in its steps but yet the overall claim of the proof is correct.... so its like "insider info" or "inside baseball" or "exercise to reader"....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To cite the blog post:

> For arguments sake, lets say that in Karp's classic paper Reducibility Among Combinatorial Problems, where he proves 21 problems NP-compete, he made a mistake on 0-1 programming.

That is, the blog author does *not* state that there *is* a mistake. It is just a gedankenexperiment.

That is, of course, not to say that there is none.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that reduction SAT to 0-1 programming contains a mistake.
Let we have a simple formula of 1 clause: (x V y V z).
Following the Karp's reduction, we will get the equation
x + y + z = 1, which is not eqivalent to the source boolean formula,
However the unequality x + y + x >= 1 is equivalent.